# Real bounded sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ such that $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|<\epsilon , n\geq m.$

Tags: real-analysis

For real sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ condition  $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|<\epsilon , n\geq m$ does't says that the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ is convergent, as counter example is the sequence $\{\sqrt{n}\}.$ What if we  add one more thing that the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ is bounded also? I  did't find any counterexample. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can take $x_n=\sin(\sqrt{n})$. As for all $a,b$ we have  $|sin(b)-\sin(a)|\leq |b-a|$, we get $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$, hence $x_{n+1}-x_n\to 0$, and if $x_n$ is convergent, then this is also the case with $x_{k^2}=\sin(k)$, known to be divergent.

Comment: ohh my god what a nice example....thanks a lot...

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a sequence walking from $0$ to $1$ at increment $1/2$. Then back down at increment $1/3$. Then back up at increment $1/4$, and so on. This is bounded, and it satisfies your condition.

Comment: can you write this sequence in nice form...thanks...

Comment: No, spend a few minutes trying to write it out yourself. It's a good experience.

Comment: are you saying like  $ 0,1/2,1/2-1/3,1/2-1/3+1/4.....$

Comment: @neelkanth I think the sequence is given by $0,1/2,1,2/3,1/3,0,1/4,...$.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb i think your sequence is correct one...

Comment: @T.Bongers Please have a look at my solution....

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

$0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4},1,\frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{5},0,\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would necessarily be convergent. Think of a sinusoid such that the step between each two terms become smaller and smaller as $n$ goes to $+\infty$.